# How to add key/value pair in Javascript object at the start

Tags: javascript

I have following object:

```
var obj = {"last_name": "john", "age": 23, "city": "London"}
```

I want to add a new element of first_name at the start of this object to look like this:

```
{"first_name": "Samuel", "last_name": "john", "age": 23, "city": "London"}
```

I know I can do `obj.first_name = "Samuel"` but it adds the new element at the end of the object. How can I add it at the start?

Comment: objects do *not* have *order* - so it doesn't matter...

Comment: Objects are different than arrays, its properties do not have a particular order, so it cannot be done.

Comment: Since ES6, object properties [have a guaranteed order](http://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html).

Comment: @ssube: That's not quite right: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219/218196

Comment: Guaranteed order for `for ... in` or `Object.keys` came with ecmascript2017. ES6 allows for terrible pitfalls.

Comment: @ASDFGerte: That's exactly wrong. There is no guaranteed order for `for...in` or `Object.keys`. See the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: @FelixKling you are correct, I forgot many of the rules. :)

Comment: @FelixKling the `2015` was a typo and i corrected it already. The version **after** es6 of course :)

Comment: **Why** do you want this or think you need this? While I can understand the need for ordered keyed collections, you seem to have a *record* for which order should be irrelevant.

Comment: If ES6 is an option you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: @ASDFGerte: I don't see how this changed. The spec says *"The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties is not specified but must conform to the rules specified below."* But the "rules specified below" do not specify an order. (and the link I posted actually points that out too)

Comment: @FelixKling The post you linked has a comment that the answer is outdated showing the behavior in ecmascript2017. The spec for es8 changed in the related parts, last time i checked. I had asked a question about this recently and noticed that the behavior changed yet again in es8 - it was about the MDN text of getOwnPropertyNames

Comment: @ASDFGerte: I can see that to be the case for `Object.keys` but not for `for...in`. But whatever :D

Comment: @FelixKling After additional debate and research i noticed it was a misunderstanding on my side - Neither `Object.keys` nor `for ... in` have a specified order in ecmascript2017 aka es8. It uses a function that has order but may rearrange it (or so i currently believe :) ). The comments on the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties) would therefore be wrong. So confusing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While objects have actually (ES5) no order, you could generate a new object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and use the new property as object to start with and assign the given object to it. The new object has properties in creation order.

```js
var object = { last_name: "john", age: 23, city: "London" };

object = Object.assign({ first_name: "Samuel" }, object);

console.log(object);
```

Comment: This solves the question, but what if there were non-enumerable properties (or getter/setter)?

Comment: @ASDFGerte, i would not rely on a order of an object. `Object.assign` copies only own enumerable properties.

Comment: This did not work: `disease_dict.assign({Select: "<td><div class='custom-control custom-checkbox'>"
                                        + "<input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input'"
                                        +"id='customCheck1' name=${" + check_name + "}>"
                                        +"<label class='custom-control-label' for='customCheck1'>"
                                        + "</label></div></td>", disease_dict });`

Answer (score 5):

I tried, It works with spread operator. Do it in below way

```
var object = { last_name: "john", age: 23, city: "London" };
var newObject= { first_name: "Samuel" };
object = {...newObject, ...object }
```

o/p: { first_name: "Samuel", last_name: "john", age: 23, city: "London" };

Answer (score 0):

Can do with spread operator, not confident about order

var object = { last_name: "john", age: 23, city: "London" };

var newObj={first_name: "Samuel" ,... object}

console.log(newObj);